# How to enable Text Detection Confidence Score for Node JS, using Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vision

My text detections, using Google Cloud Vision API, are missing confidence scores. More specifically, the scores are always 0 except for the language feature. I am using Node JS to build a firebase cloud function.

My issue is similar to https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/266. The offered solution is for Python but I need the same for Node JS.

I found the right Node JS reference for it at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/latest/vision/protos.google.cloud.vision.v1p3beta1.textdetectionparams#_google_cloud_vision_protos_google_cloud_vision_v1p3beta1_TextDetectionParams_enableTextDetectionConfidenceScore_member

but I do not know how to implement it. These references confuse me. I have yet to learn how to use them. So, any tips on how to use these references at the same time would be appreciated.

I tried to improvise and got this:

```
const imageBucket = `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`;

 const options = {
  "requests": [
    {   
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
 
 const client2 = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(options);

  const textDetectionParams = vision.TextDetectionParams({enableTextDetectionConfidenceScore: true})
  const imageContext = vision.ImageContext(textDetectionParams);
  
  
  const [textDetections] = await client2.textDetection(imageBucket, imageContext);
```

but this is returning an error:  TypeError: vision.TextDetectionParams is not a function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution to that:

```
 const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
  const imageBucket = `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`;
  
  const [textDetections] = await client.documentTextDetection(imageBucket);
```

Basically, change textDetection to documentTextDetection. This works perfectly and I can see the confidence scores now. Learn more here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting